# How do I include the "satellite assembly" language dll in setup project?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in Visual Studio 2008 and have a Windows Forms project + a setup project.

My Windows Form has Localizable set to true and when I debug I can correctly change language etcetera.

The problem occurs when I build the projects for release and install it on some test machine. Language switch do not work, and I found out that the DLL when debugging placed at e.g. folder en under debug/release folder is not included in the setup project.

2 questions:
- Is the DLLs under e.g. en what is referred as "satellite assemblies"?
- How do I get these DLLs included such that all languages are supported when installed using the setup file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the "localized resources" of a project to the setup output.